# How to submit a form to the same page and refresh content without reloading entire page

Tags: php, ajax

Basically what I'm trying to do is post comments to a page without having to refresh the entire page. Just the Comments DIV so it looks like it posted and refreshed smoothly.

The form submits to the same page it's on. Everything I've found shows me how to refresh content constantly using intervals. I just want the comments DIV to refresh when someone posts a comment.

I can't find the correct ajax code to do this the way I want.

Here is my code:

```
var submit_button = $('#submit_button');

submit_button.click(function() {

    var commentSubmitted= $('commentSubmitted').val();


    var update_div = $('#update_div');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/blog/',
        data: data,   
        success:function(html){
           update_div.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

in the same PHP file, I have the post to DB:

```
if($_POST[commentSubmitted])
{

  $query="INSERT INTO comments (commentSubmitted) VALUES ('$commentSubmitted')";
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

The HTML is for the form:

```
<form id="flow" method='post' action='/blog/'>
<textarea name='commentSubmitted' ></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Post'/>
```

The DIV containing all comments looks like so:

```
<DIV id='AllComments'>

// comments displayed here

</DIV>
```

So after submitting the form, I would like the 'AllComments' DIV to reload.

Comment: *I can't find the correct ajax code to do this the way I want* - though it sounds simple, this does require a certain level of understanding to accomplish. There's no magical JS wand to wave around and make an AJAX request work exactly the way you need it. I suggest you read up a little on the subject. Come back and ask afterwards, preferably including some code you've written.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my post with my current code.

Comment: If you are indeed able to send the request correctly to the server, you just need to return relevant HTML back to the page. Specifically, the way your code is currently designed, you need to output the comments HTML after the MySQL query.

Comment: It is after. the DB is collecting the info, but the page stays still. I have to manually refresh to see the comments DIV with new content.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use jQuery to make the ajax call to the server and retrieve the data you want.

You have two ways of retrieving the data. Either retrieve the additional comments to show in a json array and handle it with javascript, or create the html on the server side and append/replace the html in the comments section.

**Using Json**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "the_ajax_url_here",
  type: "post",
  data: {paramTitle: "paramValue", paramTitle1: "paramValue1"},
  dataType: "json"
  success: function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
});
```

**Retrieving Html**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "the_ajax_url_here",
  type: "post",
  data: {paramTitle: "paramValue", paramTitle1: "paramValue1"},
  dataType: "html"
  success: function(response) {
    // set the html of comments section to the newly retrieved html
    $("comments_section_selector").html(response);
  }
});
```

What I would do is retrieve the newly added comment in a json array and then using javascript append it to the comments section.

**edit:**
After seeing your code I have some comments that might help you.
I would personally prefer the code that handles the ajax request in a separate file.
In that file you can store the new comment and create the html to display that comment.
Then in the success function just append the new html to the comment section like so:

```
success: function(response) {
  $('#AllComments').append(response);
}
```

You can also make new comment appear on top using prepend

```
$('#AllComments').prepend(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that hope you are upto it

```
submit_button.click(function() {

    var commentSubmitted= $('commentSubmitted').val();


    var update_div = $('#update_div');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/blog/',
        data: data,   
        success:function(html){
           update_div.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Then you go to insert data

```
if($_POST[commentSubmitted])
{

  $query="INSERT INTO comments (commentSubmitted) VALUES ('$commentSubmitted')";
  mysql_query($query);
  //After Inserting data retrieve back all the comments from db
  $sql = "select * from comments";//any query and execute it
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo $data["comments"];//Echo your commenets here
  }
  exit;
}
```

Thats it